# Why won't my vh work on iphone

Tags: html, css, media-queries, mobile-safari, viewport-units

I have an image slider on top of my page and it is set to fit the screen with vh.

And when I'm looking how it looks on iPhone there is definitely something wrong. The image stretches so I have to scroll A LOT.. please help.

Here's my code:

CSS:

```
    .container-fluida{
        width: 100vw;
        height:calc(100vh - 50px);
        position: relative;
    }

    .frontpage-image-slider{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
```

Comment: Make sure your html is completely valid first: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmar-noe.com%2Fwordpress%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Support isn't perfect in IOS - http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: is there a work around i can do or something

Comment: @ZippyV thanks the validator help a lot some few errors i need to take care of. But the one error with my get header fixed it had put it in the page wrapper

Comment: Use a combo of setting meta viewport, scale 1.0 and percentage height and width. I can't test since i have no iDevices, but it should work for every modern browser, both desktop, mobile and tablet.

Comment: why not using classic `width/height: 100%`?